# I want to display the alt attribute under the image when open box modal

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

I want display the alt attribute under the image when i open box modal , i call the images from mysql .
php code :

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    <img  id="'.$row['id'].'" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2" 
     alt='.$row['caption'].' src = "data:image;base64,'.$row['image'].'" 
     style="width:100%">
    <h5 data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2">'.$row['caption'].'</h5>
```

HTML Code :

```
<div id="myModal2" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
 <span id="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</span>
    <div class="modal-content">
    <img class="img-responsive " src=""/>
    </div> 
    </div>
```

JavaScript code :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myModal2').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
        var image = $(e.relatedTarget).attr('src');
        $(".img-responsive").attr("src",image);
    });
  });
```

Comment: You aren't using `echo` in the first php code block, please edit if this not how your actual code looks.

Comment: @mickmackusa using echo for what ?

Comment: Your `while()` loop means your code is being parsed as `php`.  php will not display any html unless you use: `echo`, `print`, etc.  If you don't want to write echos, you'll need to bounce in and out of php with `?>` and <?php` tags all over the place (I don't recommend it).

Comment: it's display the images and captions , when i click the box modal it's enlarge the images , my problem is how to display the alt attribute under the images when i open the box modal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create for example `p` element inside your modal and then use `text()` function to add text to that element from `alt` attribute.

HTML:

```
<div id="myModal2" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
 <span id="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</span>
  <div class="modal-content">
    <img class="img-responsive " src=""/>
    <p></p>
  </div> 
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#myModal2').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    var image = $(e.relatedTarget).attr('src');
    $(".img-responsive").attr("src",image);
    $("#myModal2 p").text($(e.relatedTarget).attr('alt'));
  });
});
```